# In CSS what is the difference between height:0 and height not specified?

Tags: css

As far as I understand it (which is not far), a `div` of `height:0;` and a `div` with no specified height will both expand to a height required to contain their child elements. Why would you ever code `height:0` ?

(I'm sure there is a very good reason)

Comment: A `div` with `height: 0` will never expand. A `div` with no specified height will.

Comment: It might look like that it expands because the content overflows. Try to put a border, or a background color, or `overflow: hidden` to a `height: 0` element.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to delete this question, it was dumb. Oh wait, I can't now, because it's been answered. Oh well.

Comment: Not really a dumb question. No worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you are right in saying that a `div` with `height:0` expands to show its children.As you would expect, by setting the height to zero, the `div` disappears. Its children may still be shown, but the height of the `div` is zero. Try the combo:

```
#my-div{
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

In this way, anything that overflows from the `div` will be hidden and the effect of `height:0` should be more visible.

Answer (score 2):

Not true.

A div with a specific height will never expand. So if a div has content larger than the desired height, content will overflow, but the div will not expand.

Here's an example to illustrate this.

```css
#div-1 {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  background: red;
}

#div-2 {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  background: green;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
</div>
<div id="div-2">
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `height: 0` the element will not expand higher than zero pixels.

When you don't specify the height, then the element will expand to the height of its contents.

Answer (score 0):

It is huge difference between height:0 vs height no specified. Both will show the inside content but which height:0 this is content will show if you do not set overflow: hidden; but it not increase it's height based content but no specified height will show the content and its height will automatically increase, see [here][1].

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ntpr5enu/
```